# Whats the better option when looking for not null in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know what are your thoughts for this. Should I just do a condition where it checks for if a value is true or should I check if a value is not null.

```
if (
    project.homebuilder !== null &&
    project.house !== null &&
    project.manager !== null 
)
```

Wouldn't it better to check if they're true?

```
if (
    project.homebuilder &&
    project.house  &&
    project.manager 
)
```

Note: The object values initial state is null

Comment: depends on whether your object values can be other falsy values such as `0`, `undefined`, etc...

Comment: Well that depends - can it ever be null?

Comment: Depends--these structures do different things. One checks *explicitly* for `null`, one checks for truthiness. We can't guess if that's significant.

Comment: @NickParsons so in this case the object values initial state is null.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay I think this answers my question then because the initial state of the object values are null.

Comment: If you're _really_ just checking for "not null", then `!==` is your only real option.  You can try to shorten it, but why would you? The interpreter isn't going to grind to a halt just because you used a more precise equality test. And you don't get demerits for not writing the tersest possible code. In fact, verbose but precise is almost always better than terse but possibly buggy on edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will not match if the data worth `undefined` or `false` as much as `null`, so be careful. It's good to specify the target value you want to check.

```
   if (
        project.homebuilder &&
        project.house  &&
        project.manager 
    )
```

---

List of falsy values :  https://www.gobindathakur.com/javascript-falsy-values

- false (boolean false)
- null
- undefined
- 0 (number zero)
- ‘’ or “” (empty string)
- NaN